# How to shrink disk size of kvm qcow2 image?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have an image which virtual disk size says it's 17G, with disk `/dev/sda1`  only beeing full for 4.6 Gb:

```
#:/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images# virt-df -h guest1.qcow 
Filesystem                                Size       Used  Available  Use%
guest1.qcow:/dev/sda1               17G       4.6G        13G   27%
guest1.qcow:/dev/sda15             104M       3.6M       101M    4%
```

I wanted to shrink disk size to like 5.5Gb and was following this guide: http://www.mischiefblog.com/2014/09/16/resize-shrink-kvm-img-qcow2-virtual-machine-filesystem-disk-image/

That is, I logged into `guestfish` and ran `resize2fs-size /dev/sda1 5500M`. That was successful I saw the following:

```
#:/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images# virt-df -h guest1.qcow  
Filesystem                          Size       Used  Available  Use%
guest1.qcow:/dev/sda1               5.1G       4.5G       684M   87%
guest1.qcow :/dev/sda15             104M       3.6M       101M    4%
```

Then before running `qemu-image resize`, I wanted to start the guest to check if everything was fine, but after boot, I logged in and saw that `/dev/sda1` was actually 17G again. Shutting the guest down and checking with `virt-df -h guest1.qcow` indeed showed that somehow the disk automatically grew to 17G again.

Now, if I don't boot and just run `qemu-img resize --shrink guest1.qcow 5.5G` it will corrupt the disk, it seems, and the system won't boot.

Also, strangely, `qemu-img info` shows a very weird disk size info:

```
#:/var/lib/uvtool/libvirt/images# qemu-img info guest1.qcow 
image: guest1.qcow 
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 18G (19327352832 bytes)
disk size: 7.9G
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: true
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

What is 7.9Gb? Where did it come from?

What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate any help.